# expressjs routing configuration object?

Tags: node.js, express

Can you simply set all routing configurations in a single object? Basically what I'd like to do is have a file called routing.js that exports an object containing all of the routes. Having to use express.get() for every route is mundane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have a folder that holds all the files for my routes (I split them up by object). I also separate out my controllers into files as well. The route files then look like this:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var controller = require('../controllers/index');

/**
 * The API root for this object.
 */

var root = '/';

/**
 * Route definitions.
 */
var routes = function (app) {

  // get index
  app.get(root, controller.getIndex);
};

/**
 * Exports.
 */
module.exports = routes;
```

Then in my app.js file I do this which automatically loads up all of my route files and configures the 500 and 404 routes:

```
fs.readdir(__dirname + '/routes', function (err, files) {
  if (err) throw err;
  files.forEach( function (file) {
    require('./routes/' + file)(app);
  });

  /**
   * 500 page.
   */
  app.use( function (err, req, res, next) {

    if (err && err.status === 404) {
      return next();
    }

    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.render('404.html', {status: 500, url: req.url, error: ': ' + err.message});
  });

  /**
   * 404 page.
   */
  app.use( function (req, res, next) {
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.render('404.html', {status: 404, url: req.url});
  });
});
```

If you don't want to read the files in like this, the import part is this line:

```
require('./routes/' + file)(app);
```

Which allows you to use the route that was defined previously.

I do it this way to maintain control over exactly which routes are created.  If you want to automate the process you can use https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource.

This allows you to do:

```
var express = require('express'), 
    Resource = require('express-resource'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.resource('forums', require('./forum'));
```

In order to create automatically routes that point to the following functions in ./forum:

```
GET     /forums              ->  index
GET     /forums/new          ->  new
POST    /forums              ->  create
GET     /forums/:forum       ->  show
GET     /forums/:forum/edit  ->  edit
PUT     /forums/:forum       ->  update
DELETE  /forums/:forum       ->  destroy
```

If you want something even simpler, you could do this...

```
var getRoutes = [['/', controller.index], ['/post', controller.showPost]];

for (var i = 0, len= getRoutes.length; i < len; i++) {
   var path = getRoutes[i][0];
   var controller = getRoutes[i][1];
   app.get(path, controller);
}
```

Comment: this is nice, but I'm looking for something more like {'/', controller.index}

Comment: That's going to be pretty limiting as soon as you want to start adding middleware to your routes, plus you need to differentiate between `get`, `post`, `update`, and `del`.  So you're really just going to go from `app.post('/', controller.index)` to `{'post', '/', controller.index}` plus some helper code. I've updated my response to include a simple helper that would register the routes.

Comment: So basically I'd have to create an interpreter if I wanted do do it that way? Express doesn't have it built-in?

Comment: Nobody really wants to do what you are trying to do, so no, it's not built in.  You'll need to write the few lines of glue code to hook things up.  Express has do it yourself (using app.use/app.get/etc) and completely automagic (with express-resource).